# How to add margin to a Button at run time?

Tags: android, dynamic, button, margin

I have to add more than one buttons on a LinearLayout. But I want to put those buttons say 5px apart. I could not find a way to set a margin of a Button. Any idea?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use the layout_margin property of the button element. Does that not work?

```
<Button android:layout_margin="5px" (...)/>
```

## Edit

When creating a button in java, LayoutParams is used to specify margins and so.

```
Button button = new Button();
(....)
params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams();
params.leftMargin = 5;
(set params as you need)
parent.addView(button, params);
```

The LayoutParams you use must match the Layout you add your button in (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html). For a LinearLayout, use a LinearLayout.LayoutParams and set the *Margin fields accordingly.

Comment: I am new to Android!

I am confused, if I have it in XML, then how can I use while 

creating dynamically?

My code looks like this,


  btnSend = new Button(this);

        btnSend.setText("Send...");

        btnSend.setBackgroundResource (R.drawable.red_button);

        btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

   
   public void onClick(View v) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
    // Code here...
    
   }

  });

Comment: I edit my post with informations regarding dynamic button creation

Comment: Thank much for your help. I'm sorry that 

It doses not do what I want!

Say,

LinearLayout.LayoutParams lParam  = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( 
          LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT );
        
        lParam.setMargins(20, 20, 20, 20);

It adds margin to the LinearLayout. Not to the button. For example, it there is 2 buttons, side by side, it does *not* add space between the buttons! Which is my goal!

Thanks!

Comment: This is getting complicated. Can you post the code you have? Also, make sure the layoutParams is either set to the button or used in the addView method

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
//Assuming your button is in a LinearLayout as stated
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = myButton.getLayoutParams();
params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0) //left, top, right, bottom
myButton.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: that works too, except the setLayoutParams is useless. and getLayoutParams may be null. and how do you know it is a LinearLayout.LayoutParams that the button has ?

Comment: I'm not writing a program to pass testing here, it's a general idea of what is required. As I stated in the comment, I'm assuming his button is in a LinearLayout, as he stated in his original post. In this link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLayoutParams(), it is stated that `When a View is attached to a parent ViewGroup, this method must not return null`. Ergo, it will not be null in this instance.

Comment: @kcoppock,

Thanks, I think you are right that it will not return null, according your assumption that it is in LinearLayout. But, since the button is added to that layout later; in this case, it returns null. Thank you all!

Comment: @kcoppock, how to write if am using Relative Layout

Answer (score 4):

```
MarginLayoutParams params = (MarginLayoutParams) vector8.getLayoutParams();
params.width = 200; params.leftMargin = 100; params.topMargin = 200;
vector8.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Need use type of: MarginLayoutParams

Comment: this is helpfull for me

Answer (score 0):

Adding padding to the buttons would also solve your problem.  Check this out
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-formstuff.html#CustomButton

Comment: Thanks, but padding adds space inside the button area, say space between the edge and the text of the button.

Comment: try this :   setGravity(int): Specifies how to align the text by the view's x- and/or y-axis when the text is smaller than the view.

Answer (score 0):

use this code to set margin at runtime

```
  LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) btnContainer.getLayoutParams();
        params.setMargins(5, 50, 10, 0); //left, top, right, bottom
        view_whwre_set_margin.setLayoutParams(params);
```