# ExpandableListView ChildItem narrower than ParentItem

Tags: android, xml, expandablelistview, listviewitem

How to make ExpandableListView ChildItem narrower than ParentItem? I'm using custom items in my list. I've tried adding margins in my child_item.xml.
[I have sth like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08nUu.png). I want to make this lighter fields narrower.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7094459/how-to-add-margin-to-a-button-at-run-time

Comment: post code of your layouts

Comment: you can create a custom adapter with custom layout for your lists

Comment: Thank you @IvanShero. That helped.